# A WebView in a thread can't be created

Tags: android, multithreading, android-widget, android-webview, looper

i have some threads in which i create some views and prepare them to be displayed. Among them i also have a WebView. This code is executed in thread:

```
WebView lGraphWebView = null;
        try{
            lGraphWebView = new WebView(AppController.getAppController());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("info", "error: " +e );
        }
```

and it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

This is a bit strange, because when i create a simple button all is OK. So, can anyone explane to me why on creation of a WebView i get this exception and if `Looper.prepare()` can help here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, its not safe to create view outside of main thread.

In your particular case, this is not allowed, because `WebView` creates `Handler()` in its constructor for communication with UI thread. But since `Handler`'s default constructor attaches itself to current thread, and current thread does not have `Looper` running, you're getting this exception.

You might think that creating a looper thread (that must be alive at least as long as `WebView`) might help you, but this actually a risky way to go. And I wouldn't recommend it.

You should stick with creating `WebView`s in main thread. All controls are usually optimized for fast construction, as they are almost always created in UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create or manipulate views in threads other than the main UI thread. For instance, you can use the [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post to the UI thread:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       lGraphWebView = new WebView(AppController.getAppController());
   }
});
```